# Center 4 columns inside of another column with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a column of 9 and within this an additional 4 columns. I am trying to get the 4 columns to be central of the column as they are set to a max-width of 198px.

```
<div class="content col-md-9">
    <div class="item col-md-3">
        <img src="assets/img/demo/1.png" width="198" height="266" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-md-3">
        <img src="assets/img/demo/2.png" width="198" height="266" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="item col-md-3">
        <img src="assets/img/demo/3.png" width="198" height="266" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-md-3">
        <img src="assets/img/demo/4.png" width="198" height="266" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-md-3">
        <img src="assets/img/demo/5.png" width="198" height="266" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="item col-md-3">
        <img src="assets/img/demo/6.png" width="198" height="266" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
        <p class="hs-label"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content.col-md-9 > .item.col-md-3 {
    background: #ffffff;
    max-width: 198px;
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 0!important;
    margin: 7px;
}

.content.col-md-9 > .item.col-md-3 img {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.content.col-md-9 > .item.col-md-3 .hs-label {
    background: #cccccc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

As explained, each column is set to a maximum width of 198px. I need the col-md-3 to all be center of col-md-9 so that there is equal space on the left and right of the col-md-3's.

Comment: You should avoid changing the properties of the `col-*` elements. Instead just put a div inside the col and position that.

Answer (score 0):

As a most basic example, you can achieve this style of layout using the following in Bootstrap.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
      <div class="well clearfix">
        
  <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="well text-center">Test</div>
  </div>
      
  <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="well text-center">Test</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="well text-center">Test</div>
  </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="well text-center">Test</div>
  </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: For the purposes of the SO Snippet I have used `.container-fluid` and `.col-xs-*`.  I have also changed `.col-xs-9` to `.col-xs-10` to allow an equal offset on either side.  You may need to adjust this to better-suit the larger scope of your design.